# For QGIS processing algorithm python scripts, how to limit selectable layers in algorithm input when using @alg decorators

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

When using the `@alg` decorator to scaffold a processing algorithm, we use the @alg.input to declare new widgets for the interface. We can declare these as `alg.SOURCE` for layers we use in the algorithm.

Unlike the standard approach, there does not appear to be a place where we can identify allowable geometry types (Point/Line/Polygon) for the layer. I've tried adding a parameter `types=[QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString]` however, it does not appear to filter the allowable selections in the drop-down. I still get polygons and points as well.

Is this a bug because while the `@alg.input` accepts the `types=[]` parameter, it does not appear to have any impact on what appears in the dropdown?

```
import pyodbc
from PyQt5.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis import processing
from qgis.processing import alg
from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsDataSourceUri, QgsVectorLayer,\
    QgsFeatureSink, QgsWkbTypes, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem, QgsField, QgsFeature,\
    QgsVectorFileWriter, QgsProcessingException

@alg(name='roadsassessment', label='Call 3 Mobile Roads Assessment', group='bbfcall3', group_label='BBF Call 3')


@alg.input(type=alg.INT, name='APPNUM', label='Application number')
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='ELIGIBLEROADSSOURCE', types= [QgsWkbTypes.MultiLineString], label='Eligible Roads')
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='APPCOVERAGESOURCE', types=[QgsWkbTypes.MultiPolygon], label='Application coverage')
@alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, name='MOBILECOVERAGESOURCE', label='Full mobile coverage')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use [QgsProcessing.SourceType](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsProcessing.html#acad4d2322342455b53eee5701e2b3115) enum:

Options for a vector layer

```
QgsProcessing.TypeVector 
QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPoint
QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine
QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon
QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry
```

Example:

```
types= [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine, QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Kadir !  QGIS is not easy to code for me as I find I'm not very comfortable with the way their documentation is laid out.  It feels a little out of reach for me.  I'm always struggling to find the right class.

Comment: I was just like you when I started coding in QGIS.

Comment: Is there a way to select only geometryless tables?

Comment: @FlorianJenn I guess no.   `QgsProcessing.TypeVector ` may be the best option because geometryless layer is a vector layer in QGIS. Please check the docs in the link above.